# Ajax Request on another's success ( jQuery )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to run the another ajax request on one's success.

### THE CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('*[data-load-template]').each( function () {

        var template = $(this).data('load-template');
        var element = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url     : "templates/" + template + '.tpl',
            method  : "GET",
            success : function (htmlData) {
                $.ajax({
                    url     : "data/" + template + '.json',
                    method  : "GET",
                    success : function (jsonData) {
                        console.log(jsonData); // why isn't this one working???
                    }       

                });
                element.html(htmlData); // this is working
            }

        });

    });

}); // dom ready event
```

My question is why isn't this code working and how to make it work.

Comment: It should work. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Sounds like the second ajax request isn't returning successfully. Try setting up a `error` handler and see what's going wrong.

Comment: @Barmar i am getting no errors

Comment: Does the success callback from the initial request fire? What do the responses from the calls look like in your dev tools?

Comment: If you aren't getting success, you are getting error. Add an error handler and debug your code.

Comment: what's your console output?

Comment: so I added the `error : function(error) { console.log(error) }`

Comment: got the whole object in the console but it has status 200 ok

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint on the `console.log` line? Do you get there?

Comment: the error callback has three arguments, not one. Log the 3rd one.

Comment: @KevinB syntax error unexpected token

Comment: Now you're getting somewhere. what is theFirstArgument.responseText?

Comment: dont you mean type: "GET", instead of method: "GET" or am I missing something?

Comment: @KevinB response text:       `""name" : "Faiz Ahmed""`

Comment: that's not valid json.